# How to wait for a mongoose promise that is inside a function?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

I did the test below for a seed that needs to get data from the model *User*. I think my problem here is that *testFunction* is returning *name* before it's value is updated within the .then().

I clearly don't understand how the flow is working here. Anybody has an idea about why is this happening and how could I solve it? Thank in advance ;)

```
const testFunction = () => {

let name = undefined

User.find()
    .then(result => name = result[0].username)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

return name }
```

Comment: You need to convert `testFunction` to be `async` and then you can `await` like so: ```let results = User.find()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your function to be `async` and then you will be able to `await` the results of your mongoose call. For example:

```
const testFunction = async () => {
  let name = undefined;
  let results = await User.find();

  if (results && results[0] && results[0].username) {
    name = results[0].username
  } else {
    // handle error
  }

  return name;
}
```

Comment: Hi dwosk! Thank you. I could handle the problem thanks to your answer. But I have some questions. Why when I call _testFunction()_ it returns me a promise? And what are the if else from the function are to? I realized that removing them returns a name undefined but if I console.log(results) before the if statement there is already data. So I don't see the point to use the if statement. Thanks again!

Comment: I recommend you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function. When you mark it as `async` it returns a promise. The if/else block is a type guard so you don't try to access the `username` property of a null, which will throw an exception. I put it in there just to be safe.